# Simple java regex not matching

Tags: java, regex

my regex returning false, cant understand why.

```
Pattern patt = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
patt.matcher("a 18c1").matches(); //returning false
```

Also I tried `[0-9]+` , `(\\d+)`, `([0-9]+)`, they didnt work too..
Can you help me? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you use `.matches()`. What you want is [`.find()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29).

`.matches()` is a misnomer; it will try and match against the *entire input*. Regex matching is done using `.find()`:

```
final Matcher matcher = patt.matcher("a 18c1");
if (matcher.find())
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
```

Comment: Ok, then i am trying to call patt.matcher("a 18c1").group() , it returning java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found

Comment: Which is normal; you don't call `.find()`! A `Matcher` needs to be initialized. See edit.